# Google Play Content Policy

Tags: android, google-play

I've just received an email from Google telling me that one of my apps violates developer terms and I have 7 days to comply. Here's what they say:

> REASON FOR WARNING: Violation of the spam provisions of the Content
> Policy.
>
> - Do not post repetitive content.
> - Product descriptions should not be misleading or loaded with keywords in an attempt to manipulate ranking or relevancy in the
>   store’s search results.
>
> Your application will be removed if you do not
> make modifications to your application’s description to bring it into
> compliance within 7 days of the issuance of this notification.

As far as I can understand the reason they think the app description is loaded with keywords, I seriously have no idea what does the "Do not post repetitive content" refers to. Does it mean there are other apps like this in the market? Mine was first, most innovative and is the most popular in its category. Or maybe it's because something is repeating in the description (well, it isn't)?

So the question is - what is that point of Content Policy referring to? I seriously hate Google for not having a customer support. There's no one to contact to ask for details.

Comment: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136601&rd=1
Bottom of the page "contact Us".

Comment: I assure you, there's no chance they will answer :) That's Google.

Comment: @SebastianNowak They've answered me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bound to be all of those websites. Google probably thinks that this is an attempt to have lots of inbound links in order to manipulate search engine rankings. It clearly isn't but you may sort out the problem by just having one link to your website that lists where you get the content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think that the repetitive content refers to all those links?

Comment: I think that this is just a standard email from google that isn't particularly helpful. Bear in mind that I doubt anyone at google will have read your app description, it will have been fed through a system that flags it.

Answer (score 1):

How strange, can we see the App description? I would bet it's to do with something you've said in the description, repetitive content to me means posting the same thing multiple times....

EDIT: Just found this, mentions alot about the changes but still no proper description o.O

http://androidcommunity.com/google-play-app-policies-updated-with-major-changes-20120801/

Comment: Sure, it's here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amuse They probably treat the list of websites as keywords, but I see nothing repetitive here :|

Comment: Yeah, i;d guess the website list 'Amuse - Cheezburger, TFLN, FailBlog, 9gag, bash, fmylife & others' looks like using keywords, maybe if you phrased it as 'Some of the websites we have in our app are....' then use urls instead of just names? Must admit i like the look of your app, gonna download it lol :P

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. But still the problem remains with the "repetitive content" thing :|

Comment: Well it's an automated system so i reckon they've just put an automated message on. e.g this report http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2012-08/03/indie-dev-google-crackdown                       That says at the bottom they were using keywords and they got the automated warning like you

Comment: How do you know it's an automated system? Application description wasn't altered since months, if it's automated I'd receive such email long time ago.

Comment: Well that news report about the crackdown only came out at the start of this month, http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2012-08/02/google-play-rules  thats the announcement that was august 2nd. The other report i posted above mentions that its an automated system :) They only started this crackdown this month

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that all those links (simply too many) constitute "Violation of the spam provisions of the Content Policy" note the word **SPAM** in the sentence.

I think that "repetative" is not a relevant notion in this warning, except for the repetition of many links (play of words).

Also from the SEO (serch engine optimisation) perspective, using the names of popular webistes creates search engine links and constitute rigging of the webpage ranking...