# What do "Do not post repetitive content" in google play policy mean?

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Play Content Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051362/google-play-content-policy)

I know this isn't exactly the right place..But i have tried several forums and couldn't get any answer..so

My app was removed from google play last day..i am trying to understand why..

There was no warning...Yesterday morning i received a mail from google team that my app has been removed...The only reason they told me was:

> Do not post repetitive content

Nothing else...I admit that i had some keywords in the page(which i din't knew then as 'not allowed')..But according to the mail that wasn't the reason for removal..

So which all apps are considered as 'repetitive content'.?

The only problem that i can think of is one of my other app "Animal Sounds For babies"...And the removed app is "Automobile Sounds for babies kids".

I admit that both of them had similar code and UI. But from a user's perspective,they serve different purpose(i think).

So i was wondering if the removal was due to

1. Similarity between codes(and UI) in my existing app,even though they did different things..And google play do not ALLOW this....
2. There is some filtering mechanism which automatically compares and removes apps with similar data structures.So the app gets removed without any humans reviewing it..
3. I am not allowed to post any app that already exists in google play(not likely)

I need to know the real reason before i resubmit..Can i reupload if i change the UI and class structure from my existing App..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051362/google-play-content-policy

Comment: http://news.cnet.com/8301-1035_3-57484359-94/google-play-developer-policy-updated-to-fight-spam/

Comment: So is it all about the description??
And not about what the app is?or its similarity to existing app? i need to be sure..Google says repeated violation cancels the account..